# How to get ios permissions list from .ipa file

Tags: java, ios, ios-permissions

I am using java 1.8 and spring-boot-starter-parent 1.5.1.RELEASE version.

I am trying to get list of permissions from .ipa file. I did fetch [Android permissions](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html) from .apk, like extracted AndroidManifest.xml from .apk and get get permissions from that xml file.

```
{
  "permissions": [
    "android.permission.INTERNET",
    "android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE",
    "android.permission.BLUETOOTH",
    "android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN",
    "android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED",
    "android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION",
    "android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE",
    "android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION",
    "android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
    "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
    "android.permission.BATTERY_STATS",
    "android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"
  ]
}
```

Like the same way, Is there any way to get permissions for iOS?

I have extracted .ipa file using the java code, it returns the two directories as "Payload" and "Symbols". The Payload directory contains the "Info.plist" file.

Comment: There are no permission in the `info.plist` you can only check whether the persion description text are set.

Comment: iOS permission system works differently: you just ask to use a feature and the user then either denies or allows it. Just like newer Androids finally do it. So you cannot reliably get possible permission lists anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for your reply rckoenes! Is any other file having the permissions list??

Answer (score -1):

**You can add permission according to your requirement in info.plist.**

You can check this link [add permission in info.plist](https://iosdevcenters.blogspot.com/2016/09/infoplist-privacy-settings-in-ios-10.html)

```
<key>NSAppleMusicUsageDescription</key>
<string>${PRODUCT_NAME} Music Usage</string>

<key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
<string>${PRODUCT_NAME} Microphone Usage</string>


<key>NSCalendarsUsageDescription</key>
<string>${PRODUCT_NAME} Calendar Usage</string>

<key>NSContactsUsageDescription</key>
<string>${PRODUCT_NAME} Contact fetch</string>

<key>NSHealthShareUsageDescription</key>
<string>${PRODUCT_NAME} Health Description</string>

<key>NSHealthUpdateUsageDescription</key>
<string>${PRODUCT_NAME} Health Updates</string>

<key>NSHomeKitUsageDescription</key>
<string>${PRODUCT_NAME} HomeKit Usage</string>

<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>${PRODUCT_NAME} Use location always</string>

<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>${PRODUCT_NAME} Camera Usage</string>

<key>NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription</key>
<string>${PRODUCT_NAME} BluetoothPeripheral</string>

<key>NSLocationUsageDescription</key>
<string>${PRODUCT_NAME} Location Updates</string>

<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>${PRODUCT_NAME} WhenInUse Location</string>

<key>NSMotionUsageDescription</key>
<string>${PRODUCT_NAME} Motion Usage</string>

<key>kTCCServiceMediaLibrary</key>
<string>${PRODUCT_NAME} MediaLibrary Usage</string>

<key>NSSpeechRecognitionUsageDescription</key>
<string>${PRODUCT_NAME} Speech Recognition Usage</string>

<key>NSVideoSubscriberAccountUsageDescription</key>
<string>${PRODUCT_NAME} Video Subscribe Usage</string>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>${PRODUCT_NAME} PhotoLibrary Usage</string>

<key>NSRemindersUsageDescription</key>
<string>${PRODUCT_NAME} Reminder Usage</string>

<key>NSSiriUsageDescription</key>
<string>${PRODUCT_NAME} Siri Usage</string>
```